# Description environment in a frame

Tags: beamer, description

A `beamer` document is not compiling, I couldn't find why; here is a **MWE**

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Berlin} 
    %\usecolortheme{whale} 
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

    \begin{document}

%\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Introduction}


\begin{frame}{languaje}

\begin{description}

\item hello \rightarrow comunicate.

\item aja \rightarrow again.

\end{description}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Terminal just outputs:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.25 \end{frame}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\rightarrow` needs to be in math mode, just as the error message tells you.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{languaje}
    \begin{description}
        \item hello $\rightarrow$ comunicate.
        \item aja $\rightarrow$ again.
    \end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @santimirandarp You're welcome!

Comment: Ohhh, no...haha, just have made a question about that expression on English usage forum.

Comment: @santimirandarp Oh, what a coincidence!